# How to assign `trunsaction_id` to each `user_id`

Tags: python, django

I want to assign `trunsaction_id` to each `user_id`.

The user model is

```
class User(models.Model):
    trunsaction_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
```

When I run this code, `trunsaction_id` is assigned for each registration. Is it possible to assign `trunsaction_id` to each `user_id`? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are trying to use a composite primary key, this is not supported by Django. See the documentation [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys).

If you are trying to get a column with those 2 fields combined, you could try the solution below.

However depending on your need you may be better off doing this in your Querysets. Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

```
class User(models.Model):
    trunsaction_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    @property
    def composite(self):
        return self.user_id + "_" + self.trunsaction_id
```

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur codes,but I cannot understand how to use composite method return.I wanna put the return to User model, so I wrote `user_trunsaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)` but I cannot understand how to put the id to this column.

Comment: Remove the `@property` and try this: 
`user_trunsaction_id = ''.join([trunsaction_id, '_', user_id]`

Comment: Is it mean I should replace `user_trunsaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)` into `user_trunsaction_id = ''.join([trunsaction_id, '_', user_id]` in User model?I wrote it, but TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, CharField found error happens.

Comment: Sorry -  `user_trunsaction_id = ''.join([str(trunsaction_id), '_', user_id]`. You need to translate your uuid4 to a string.

Comment: I wrote `user_trunsaction_id = ''.join([str(trunsaction_id), '_', str(user_id)]`,but db does not have user_trunsaction_id column, and does not have its data.Of course,I run makemigrations&migrate,so I really cannot understand why the column is not there.How can I fix this?

Comment: It's basically a calculated field, so you'll be able to access the field as a property in python. Just myobject.user_trunsaction_id. It depends on what you want to do of course, but you don't need everything to show up in the database if it just duplicates existing data.

Comment: I wrote  `print(User.user_trunsaction_id) `,so <django.db.models.fields.CharField>_<django.db.models.fields.UUIDField> is shown.I do not know I can understand ur message accurately,but is ur message meaning db is not shown user_trunsaction_id?Can't I access user_trunsaction_id from db?

Comment: Correct - if you need an actual column in you database you'll have to handle that through the insert. But the whole purpose of Django is to remove you from the direct database interaction. If you are needing something specific from the DB rather than the Django model then maybe Django isn't the tool you're looking for.